# How to distinguish between several instances of Mathematica?

Tags: notebooks

Say, I have three opened notebooks Untitled-1, Untitled-2, Untitled-3 in first instance of Mathematica and three notebooks Untitled-1, Untitled-2, Untitled-3 in second instance of Mathematica.
How do I distinguish which notebook belong to which instance? Is it possible to have notebooks of one instance to have different window border color then notebooks of another instance? Preferably that it would be done automatically - i.e. each new instance of Mathematica would choose different color of window.

Comment: It may help to know what is the motivation for having two to more instances of Mathematica.

Comment: Because usually when one notebook of Mathematica crashes then all other notebooks of the same instance crash too. But notebooks of another instance are unaffected. That is why I always use several instances of Mathematica, but then I am confused, which notebook belong to one instance and which to the other.

Comment: When you open a new notebook, save it with a name that indicates the instance used.

Comment: I do not want to save anything before work is finished otherwise I would have many saved files with rubbish. I work with untitled notebooks. When I am happy with the result and the notebook is worthy to be saved only then I save it.

Comment: You could have all files open by default with a docked cell that contains the name of the instance of Mathematica.  I suppose you could direct each instance of Mathematica to open two different init.m files that you modified to do this.  You could also do window color or anything else.

Comment: "I do not want to save anything before work is finished otherwise I would have many saved files with rubbish." So what, are you saving space? It should be no problem for the current level of technology. Save the intermediate result in some temporary folder and copy converged final results to the result folder when ready.

Comment: @B flat: Nice to know "I could have" but you did not write "how to do it". How I could have all files open by default with a docked cell that contains the name of the instance of Mathematica?